# React implementation in Wordpress site: webpack loader for video missing

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, webpack, wordpress-theming

I've built a React 18 project and I've been asked to set it up on a Wordpress site. I've followed the [handy guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKqogVcqDHA&t=497s) by Brad from [LearnWebCode](https://www.youtube.com/@LearnWebCode) on youtube

His guide comes with a boilerplate code folder containing a theme that can be uploaded on wordpress with the React support built-in.

It works fine and creates a compiled build via npm run build.

My issue is implementing a .mp4 file that returns an error after running npm run build:

ERROR in "video.mp4"
Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' '
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

I've searched online a bit and it seems like a common issue with webpack that has no loaders for video type files. I'm not really familiar with webpack and since the folder doesn't come with webpack.config.js I thought I could just add it in with the correct loader. Is it possible?

[image]